# Restful context or entity?

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture

What's the best approach to bring information about an object in a Rest API?

1. All the entire object always:

   ```
   Request:
   GET /user/{idUser}

   Response:
   {
   id,
   name,
   birthday,
   street,
   city,
   state,
   country
   }
   ```
2. Part that matters in an object, identified by context:

   ```
   Request:
   GET /user/address/{idUser}

   Response:
   {
   id,
   street,
   city,
   state,
   country
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

(2) should be avoided because it leads to a proliferation of endpoints. (1) is acceptable, but may be a performance hit because it pushes more information than is required over the wire. If you **test** the performance and find it unacceptable, you can provide something like this:

```
GET /users/bob?fields=id,street,city,state,country
{
    id,
    street,
    city,
    state,
    country
}
```